# prove: ∃x ∃y (Cube(x) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ x ≠ y ∧ ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = x ∨ z = y)))

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

I need a formal (Fitch) first order logic proof for:

∃x ∃y (P(x) ∧ P(y) ∧ x ≠ y ∧ ∀z (P(z) → (z = x ∨ z = y)))

Given

∃x ∃y (P(x) ∧ P(y) ∧ x ≠ y)

∀x ∀y ∀z ((P(x) ∧  P(y) ∧ P(z)) → (x = y  ∨ x = z ∨ y = z))

Any tips or help would be appreciated,

Bob Miller

Comment: welcome to philosophy.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is confusing to me. Say `P` is `is a dog?` and `x` is `Fido` (a dog) and `y` is `Rover` (also a dog). Then ∃x ∃y (P(x) ∧ P(y) ∧ x ≠ y) is valid. How can we then believe ∀z (P(z) → (z = x ∨ z = y)))? Are all dogs either Fido or Rover? What about poor Spot? The situation doesn't seem to get any better if `P` is `is a cubic number?`, as is implied by your title. There we can have `x=8` and `y=27` and yet still `z=64`. What am I missing?

Comment: Consider 2nd premise; with your example : **(Dog(Fido) ∧ Dog(Rover) ∧ Dog(Spot)) → (Fido = Rover ∨ Fido = Spot ∨ Rover = Spot)**. But **Fido = Rover** is ruled out by 1st premise; thus we get : **Fido = Spot ∨ Rover = Spot**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But both `Fido = Spot` and `Rover = Spot` are false, so  `Fido = Spot ∨ Rover = Spot` is false. So what is this whole proof telling us? I took the ∀z clause to be a conclusion based on the ∃x ∃y premise, but if it's also a premise, then what is the conclusion? What are we proving?

Comment: Why you conclude that both Fido = Spot and Rover = Spot are false ? You are assuming the existence of a third dog named **Spot** and you conclude that either Fido = Spot or Rover = Spot; thus, there is no "third dog".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, so the "all z" thing is a premise, an axiom, taken as given, there can be no third dog. Ok. So can you help me understand what is being proven here, as in "what are the inputs, and what are the outputs"? I'm unversed when it comes to logic, but it seems to me that if both the "exists x, exists y" and the "all z" clauses are premises, they're both inputs, then there's no output, nothing to prove. We just have a string of assertions we take "as is".

Comment: Why are you trying to produce a Fitch formal proof if you do not know what is a *derivation* and its nomenclature : assumptions, rules, conclusion, etc ?

Comment: I'm not trying to produce a Fitch formal proof. I am not OP, I'm just a bystander. But nevermind, now I get it. I had misread the question. The output is listed first and the two inputs listed underneath that. I didn't get that at first. Never mind, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @DanBron - no problem; if you need the "basics" (and not specifically about Fitch) you have to start from some Lectures Notes ot Textbook about Math (or Formal) Logic. The proof system used by Fitch is a variant of [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/).

Comment: The "input" are the *premises* (the "given") of the *argument* (assertions assumed as true for the context of the argument). The "output" is the *conclusion* (the "sought") to be proved, i.e. to be derived **from** the premises by way of the *inference rules* of the proof system.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that much I know, but from the formatting of the question I had trouble identifying what were the premises and what were the conclusions. In re-reading the question, it is now clear to me that OP listed the conclusion first, and the premises second, which is what had confused me. It's all clear now. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to "practice", you have to start from some simpler example, like proving that **∀x Dog(x)** implies **∃x Dog(x)**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It doesn't if there are no dogs....

Answer (score 2):

Use **∃**-elim twice with 1st premise to get :

> **P(a) ∧ P(b) ∧ a ≠ b**.

Use **∀**-elim with 2nd premise to get :

> **(P(a) ∧ P(b) ∧ P(z)) → (a = b ∨ a = z ∨ b = z)**.

Assume:

> [A] **P(z)**

and unpack the first above to get :

> **¬ (a=b)**

and the second above to get:

> **¬ (a=b) → (a = z ∨ b = z)**

and by *modus ponens* (i.e. **→**-elim) derive:

> **a = z ∨ b = z**.

By **→**-intro (Conditional Proof) we get:

> **P(z) → (a = z ∨ b = z)**,

discharging "temporary" assumption [A], and then **∀z [ P(z) → (a = z ∨ b = z)]**, by **∀**-intro (no **z** free in the premises or assumptions left).

Now by **∧** we "re-build":

> **P(a) ∧ P(b) ∧ a ≠ b ∧ ∀z [ P(z) → (a = z ∨ b = z)]**

followed by **∃**-intro twice to get:

> > **∃x∃y ( P(x) ∧ P(y) ∧ x ≠ y ∧ ∀z [ P(z) → (x = z ∨ y = z)] )**.